# Are improperly set engineered truss gussets a serious concern?

Tags: attic

I went up into the attic of my house and noticed that the intermediate beam of the roof truss has come loose from the rake.

Should I call a professional to fix it, or can I leave it like that?

I called a pro to repair my ventilation system. He noticed that the metal mending plates are loose and **said that this is more urgent than the ventilation system and should be repaired ASAP**. almost all of the trusses looks like this one.

Do you think that it's urgent or he is just overselling me

[image]

[image]

**Question update :**

The professional who alerted me about this issue came today and provided me with a quote for reinforcement. However, I find it too expensive. I can do the job myself using wooden planks, screws, and clamps.

Here is his proposed solution in the quote:
Fastening with staples using a 3cm * 10cm wooden piece over a length of 50cm.

My question is, is using screws a good solution? Considering that with screws, I would need to drill into the wood.

Should I use two regular screws, or should I use a bolt to secure the three pieces (the two new planks and the rafter)?

I want to buy two clamps to hold the wooden planks in place before screwing them. What will be the required clamping force to reposition the rafter and the brace?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're concerned that the metal mending plate is a bit loose? You're concerned about the tiny gap between pieces of lumber? What, _exactly_ is the concern? Do any/all of the other trusses look like that too?

Comment: yes, i'm concerned that the metal mending plate is loose AND yes almost all of the trusses looks like this one.

Comment: Is this a roof truss assembly, or something built on site?  Looks like the rafter was just sat on the post (or is it a diagonal truss member?), and then the plate added after the fact to keep the rafter from sliding off the post (or truss member).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your picture, but it doesn't look like this particular mending plate was ever actually pushed into the wood - I don't see the holes that would indicate it was there then backed out. With that in mind, then it's probably not *critical* that this get repaired *right this minute*. (How long has the house been standing with these like this?) However, peace of mind definitely dictates that they should be repaired, and probably sooner rather than later.

Usually, the factory uses a press of some sort to push both plates over the joint at the same time. Since you probably won't have the luxury of deconstructing the roof and getting the trusses into a large press to do that, the next best thing is to hold a small sledge hammer on one side of the truss, while you bang the plate in with a hammer from the other side. The sledge will help brace the joint while you hit it. For this particular one right at the roof, it's probably not necessary, but if there are others mid-span somewhere it would probably be pretty useful to do so, otherwise a lot of the hammer energy will just go into flexing the 2x4 and it will take more hits to get the plate to fully seat.

Of course, you could call in a carpenter to climb up into the roof to do this for you, but that would violate the DIY spirit here... ;)

My only concern about DIY in this case is the fact that you've got a tile roof. All that shaking, especially for the joints right below the roof *could* damage a tile or several. If you hire someone to do it and a tile gets damaged, it's on them to repair the roof. If you DIY, then it's on you to repair it. Having *never* worked with a tile roof, I'm not sure how sturdy those things are or how much of a factor this should be in your decision.

---

As suggested by [Ecnerwal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/275038/are-improperly-set-engineered-truss-gussets-a-serious-concern/275041?noredirect=1#comment567870_275041) you could also clamp it to squeeze it without pounding.

If I were to do that, I'd want to use a parallel clamp with a large face to apply even pressure, or put some plywood/OSB (or, even better, a couple of pieces of metal) against the mending plate then squeeze.

Example of a parallel clamp:
[image]
<sup>Source: [HarborFreight.com](https://www.harborfreight.com/24-in-parallel-clamp-58752.html?_br_psugg_q=parallel+clamp)
Note that for all the flack HF takes, these are actually pretty highly rated clamps and are very reasonably priced.
Just a fan, not an employee.</sup>

If you use a standard F-clamp or C-clamp (without any padding material to spread the force) they have such small pressure points you'd bend the plate getting one bit clamped down and it would make the next one more difficult. Also, it would take a long time because the pressure points on that type of clamp are so small.

---

Based on the contractor's proposed solution:

If the house is actually moving enough to cause the mending plates to come loose, adding staples is going to do nothing for you - they'll simply pull out, too.

After pressing the mending plates back in, adding plywood gussets and *screwing* them in would help. You could use either wood screws (long enough to go through the plywood & about 2/3 of the depth of the existing truss) or bolts, drilled all the way through with large fender washers on each side between the wood and the bolt head/nut.

#### However...

The biggest concern is *why is your house moving enough to pull these mending plates apart?*

Something odd is going on here. Those mending plates shouldn't come out unless the manufacturing quality was very low to begin with...

You may want to engage the services of a structural engineer to look at the trusses and assess them for suitability for purpose, then have him make a full analysis of the structure. Is the house settling? Is it subject to high winds that are causing uplift? You've got a tile roof, were the trusses originally designed for a different type of roof and the tiles now weight too much? (I'd think that would cause different problems, but who knows...)

Squeezing the plates back in and applying gussets over them are simply band-aids and don't do anything to address the root problem of *why* this is happening. You may stop the damage here only to find it happening elsewhere next year...

Comment: I agree on all counts, and excellent advice regarding roofing damage potential. If anything, I'd run some screws through the gussets to snug them up. It's not a serious concern, though, as they're primarily about positioning with intermediate webs.

Comment: You could use a clamp to squeeze the teeth back in without pounding and shaking the roof.

Comment: Excellent idea, @Ecnerwal. Answer updated.

Comment: But a parallel clamp like the one shown is not going to generate anywhere near the pressure/force needed to seat the metal truss plate.

Comment: I beg to differ: "Durable ergonomic handle applies up to 1300 lb. clamping force". That's well within the common range for these clamps and I'm fairly certain that it's more than enough to push those tines into the wood. (Quote from linked source page.)

Comment: Mitek makes a portable site press, for repairing or building trusses on site.  They claim 5 tonnes and 10 tonnes of force, where 1 tonne = 1,000 kg or 2,200 lbs.  So 5 tonnes = 11,000 lbs, about 10x more than the hand clamp you showed.

Comment: While more may be better, I'm willing to bet that clamp would be sufficient, especially for the price. Maybe we should just agree to disagree...

Comment: @FreeMan I updated the pictures. I tried pounding and that made things worse. I'll try squeezing as you suggested. thank you

Comment: Yeah, the load potential of a tool is often far and away from the load _required_ for a job. Heck, my hammer, wielded by my massive, rippling forearm, can generate over several lbs-ft of force. The three penny nails I use for my dollhouses don't call for nearly that many.

Comment: I'll use the clamp to squeeze the two pieces together. any idea about how to keep them together without hammering nails? like this one but less expensive (need it for 20 joints) of https://www.amazon.fr/Faithfull-Presse-%C3%A0-chants-65-mm/dp/B0054OE6MA/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2GZ5YQTNMGA9C&keywords=Presse+%C3%A0+deux+chants&qid=1687979804&sprefix=presse+%C3%A0+deux+chants%2Caps%2C88&sr=8-1

Comment: If you're really worried about it, you could drive a couple of screws into each one with a fender washer under the screw head to help keep them in place. However, IMHO, that's just a band-aid on a bigger problem... If they're coming out by themselves, you've got something else going on that's causing it and I'd get someone out to figure out why they're coming loose. It may be worth a new question here to see if you can figure out why they're coming loose.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I updated my question with some news today

Comment: @makouda note the update at the bottom of my answer

Answer (score 1):

The tiny gap between the upright and the top chord is inconsequential.

The plate is the normal connector between pieces of the truss and is not there to "mend" any issue.

While not optimal, It is not unusual for an attachment plate to be slightly warped and a few courses of teeth may not be imbedded in the wood.  This does not cause a great compromise in the strength of the truss, as they are designed to withstand weight vertically.

It is not apparent in the photo that most or all of the plates teeth are not imbedded.   If that is the case A repair should be enacted.  A gusset should be attached to both sides of the truss to help withstand lateral forces.

If just the few outside rows of teeth are loose, a couple nails on that end of the plate will help.

Comment: you think they are inconsequential? the two pieces are moving from each other !!!!

Comment: @ Makouda,  You changed pics. The comments I had were regarding the only  pic that was posted that showed a tiny, yes , inconsequential gap.  If you had pics that showed the pieces are actually moving,  you should have posted them with the question originally.  This isn't a "let's see who I can catch game."   Good Luck.