# Why use staples to secure the purlin and the strut instead of wooden dowels?

Tags: attic

as you can see in this picture, staples are used to secure the purlin and the strut instead of wooden dowels.

Now the staples are coming loose. I called a professional, and they told me they will reinforce everything with wooden dowels and screws.

Another professional told me that it was a total scam and that I should never do that. They said I should redo the staples.

Is it true that I need to redo the staples? For them, using wooden dowels is not a solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Movement of the two pieces in different directions.  The reason why will depend on a lot more information than just a small picture.

Comment: Using the staples/plates allow for easy attachment and can be put back.  Screws/dowels/other attachments will probably split the wood with that movement.  Depending on the splitting, the joint would need to be moved or replacement wood will be needed if bad enough.

Comment: Are all of the fasteners coming loose like that? Or does it seem to be confined to an odd instance or two?

Comment: yes it's confined to may 6 at most. but this is the most advanced one

Comment: The joint *really* should not be moving so much that it forces those plates to pull out like that. I would cut a piece of 3/4" plywood for each side, large enough to go well past the edges of the existing plates, and then use 4 or 5 long bolts with large washers to clamp it all together.

Comment: @brhans but wouldn't that  cause the plate to break with stress if you press them together with plywood for each side?

Comment: Those plates are typically installed in the roof truss factory by using a big hydraulic press to squeeze them together from both sides at once. Bolting it all together with plywood won't put any unusual stress on it.

Comment: @brhans why using plywood instead of whole timber? the professional suggested whole timber like this one. does that make a difference?
https://www.google.com/search?q=chevron+bois&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiomoryl_L_AhXxoUwKHTe9AuoQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=chevron+bois&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgcIABCKBRBDOggIABCABBCxAzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BAgAEANQwQdYmRJgmxRoAHAAeACAAUyIAegFkgECMTOYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=xY-iZOijC_HDsgK3-orQDg&bih=886&biw=1670#imgrc=tEXJyYEQuexEcM

Comment: I'm confused - in your question you write about "wooden dowels". [Wooden Dowels](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS991US993&sxsrf=AB5stBgGbOWsh2UM0Otro8LpsXYXm-2sHg:1688387462442&q=wooden+dowels&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEnsS3xfL_AhURF1kFHU5xDocQ0pQJegQICRAB&biw=2560&bih=1297&dpr=1.5) are a completely different thing to what you're now referring to as "whole timber".

Comment: Yeah, I'm not getting where dowels could even be used here.

Comment: I suggested plywood because that's what is commonly used for [gussets when building roof trusses](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS991US993&sxsrf=AB5stBjpwT9Ddq9KJSD62xMgbRBz6JyLww:1688387614814&q=roof+truss+with+plywood+gussets&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpppiAxvL_AhUbElkFHb4SBeAQ0pQJegQICBAB&biw=2560&bih=1297&dpr=1.5), but whole pieces of timber combined with the existing metal plates would probably work well enough.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are these mending plates (or "staples") used instead of wooden dowels or some other fastening method?

Because they're a fast, easy and cheap method for the manufacturer to assemble hundreds of thousands of trusses. If they used other methods, the price for trusses would go up, increasing the price of the whole house, and that would dissuade more people from purchasing new houses.

They are also safe, reliable and code approved (in many locales - we don't know where you live, so can't vouch for that). The trusses for my garage roof were assembled like this and were installed nearly 30 years ago and I haven't had a lick of trouble with them (despite overloading them as attic storage).

As was noted several times in your [other question about these trusses](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/275038/are-improperly-set-engineered-truss-gussets-a-serious-concern) there is something else going on here that's causing these joints to fail. There is some sort of movement of the structure, due to wind, settling, seismic activity or something else, that is causing the joints to move enough to pull these plates out. You should ***very seriously*** consider getting a structural engineer on site to assess the trusses *and the whole house* to determine what's going on and how to mitigate the movement.

You can simply patch up the joints (as discussed in that other question), but it will only be putting a band-aid on the situation. You really need to find the root cause of the problem (maybe it's even tree roots!) and fix that. Only *then* will you be able to comfortably believe that your fix to these mending plates be permanent.

Comment: The staples coming out is a symptom. They're not supposed to come loose for the lifetime of the house. Something else is wrong, and if that's not fixed, the wooden dowels and screws will also come off in time. In short, the connection failed because something else move far more than it should have.

Comment: well, some expert came, he said It is built on clay soil, and the clay moves. It is a single-story house. no immediate danger for the inhabitants. We live with it and we patch it if needed

Comment: Many houses (like all those around you), @makouda, are built on clay soil. It still shouldn't move and settle that much. You don't indicate what kind of "some expert" came to look at your house, but you may consider getting a local foundation expert, or even better, a licensed structural engineer to come look at your place. Some movement is expected. This much movement seems (in my not-professional opinion) a bit extreme. It is, however, your house and your head, so do as you see fit.